# Replacement for RBuilder in the new kotlin-react

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

i am trying to be a good developer and get on the hook/functional component train

i build my components using kotlin-react

i used to be able to write something like

```
private fun RBuilder.buildNavLi(canBeUsedInRouter: ICanBeUsedInRouter, _cb: (() -> Unit)?=null) {
    li("nav-item") {
        child(navbarLinkLi) {
            attrs {
                ctx = canBeUsedInRouter
                cb = _cb ?: ::closeMenus
            }
        }
    }
}
```

looks like RBuilder is gone....

would i just replace this with an FC, something like

```
external interface INavLinkLi:Props{
    var ctx: ICanBeUsedInRouter
    var hisLocation: history.Location
}

val NavLinkLi = FC<INavLinkLi>{ p ->
    li {
        className = ClassName("nav-item ${if(p.hisLocation.pathname == p.ctx.path) "active" else null}")
        NavLink{
            to = p.ctx.path
            className = ClassName("nav-link")
            +p.ctx.linkTxt
        }
    }
}
```